# NFA automata with ϵ moves proof

Tags: automata, finite-automata, proof-techniques

let's say L is a regular language.
And there in an NFA automata with epsilon moves A,in which for every accepting state δ(q,σ)=Ø.
How can I prove that there must be an automata A as defined for L?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some intuition how to build such NFA.

Because L is a regular language, then we can find deterministic finite automata F which accepts this language. Based on that we will build our NFA. Let's add epsilon transitions from all F's accepting states to new state which will be the only accepting state in our NFA. You can now prove, that such automata will accept L.