# Terms and definitions for regular language and NFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

let's say L is a regular language,what term does L should uphold so that there is an NFA without  epsilon moves,in which for every accepting state δ(q,σ)=Ø?I can think of some terms like that the last letters can't hold a power,but I was wandering if there is a formal definition?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  What is meant by "What term does L should uphold"?  What do you mean by a term?  What do you mean by a power?

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a regular language. There exists a NFA for $L$ in which $\delta(q,\sigma)=\varnothing$ (for every final state $q$ and every symbol $\sigma$) if $\lambda\notin L$.

We can make this into a characterization: iff $\lambda\notin L$ or $L = \{ \lambda\}$.

Comment: It seems that the construction for this normal form for finite automata was given in an [answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/68556/4287) to one of your related questions.